# PHP: Declare array element has value same specify other element?

Tags: php, arrays, element, declare

Please see the example:

```
$array = array('001' => 'A', '002' => 'B', '002' => value of 001);
```

I want to declare an array like above. But I need the value of element 002 is always same of element 001. How can I do that?

Please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: can you show your expected array

Comment: Where are the values coming from? You can save value to a variable and set to the array index. But your question does not clarify to give a more definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

To make possible that value of `$array['002']` is **always** the same of `$array['001']` you need to assign it by reference:

```
$array = array( '001' => 'A' );
$array['002'] = &$array['001'];
//              -
```

The normal assignment create a copy of original value in new variable, so — when the original variable change — the new created maintain old value. Using keyword `&` we can do an assignment by reference: by this way, new variable points to original variable (like an alias, or a symbolic link for files) and reflects its change.

Now, writing this:

```
$array['001'] = 'B';
echo $array['002'];
```

the result is:

```
B
```

because `$array['002']` reflects `$array['001']` new value.

---

Read more about [References in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Comment: Absoooooluuuuuuutely :)

Comment: Thank you. But we can not declare in one statement like on my post. Right?

Comment: No. because the array is not yet inited.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question does not clarify where the values are coming from, i'd just say you may use

```
$val1 = 'A';
$array = array(
    '001' => $val1,
    '002' => $val1,
);
```